# Why is the graph y=sin(x/y) so grainy/messy?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, implicit-function

I was just plotting random functions, and observed that the graph of y=sin(x/y) looks like randomly scattered grains or threads along the x axis! Same goes with sin(y/x). 
So what is going on with the function there? Is it just a rendering issue?

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: $x=y\times \sin^{-1} y$. Make's some sense to you? It's not all messy, but you are actually looking at a compact $arcsin$ function

Comment: @TheDeadLegend what do you mean by compact?

Comment: By compact , I mean that value of $arcsin (y)$ is bounded and kinda periodic (I can't find the word exactly) @Perceptioner

Answer (score 1):

For every $0<|y|\le 1$ there are many solutions $x$:
$$
\frac{x}{y}=
\begin{cases}
\arcsin y+2\pi k,\\
\pi-\arcsin y+2\pi k\\
\end{cases}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
x=\begin{cases}
y\arcsin y+2\pi k y,\\
-y\arcsin y+(\pi+2\pi k) y\\
\end{cases}
$$
Try to plot the dependence $x=x(y)$ for $k=0,\pm 1,\pm 2$ to see what happens and then switch the axes.

Comment: @Perceptioner, this explains what is was trying to convey